# Multiple Task Panes - Office JS Excel

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I finally got my "dialog" code working for gathering simple user input when I decided that I would prefer to utilize the `Task Pane` if possible. I've been investigating multiple taskpanes and have it working two different ways. But, I am using a `Shared Runtime` and read the below.

The following [quote from MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime#multiple-task-panes) says this:

> Don't design your add-in to use multiple task panes if you are
> planning to use a shared runtime. A shared runtime only supports the
> use of one task pane. Note that any task pane without a `<TaskpaneID>`
> is considered a different task pane.

Is there a best way to utilize multiple taskpanes and is this OK? Does this mean multiple OPEN taskpanes and/or taskpanes w/ different `<TaskpaneID>`? I won't need two `taskpanes` running at the same time, they are simply for gathering user input and running a subroutine. I haven't tested extensively my setup yet, but so far, I'm able to open the taskpanes just fine w/ different HTML files.

My first attempt (working) was to have one `TaskPane` defined in the XML w/ a script which redirects the page loaded after `taskpane.html` to the desired page.

I did this via the following function in the `taskpane.js` which is called from a `command` add-in:

```
Office.onReady((info) => {

});

function Do_OpenURLInTaskPane(URL, event) {
    console.log("URL:"+URL)
    location.href = URL
    event.completed();
    return true;
};


function getGlobal() {
    return typeof self !== "undefined"
        ? self
        : typeof window !== "undefined"
            ? window
            : typeof global !== "undefined"
                ? global
                : undefined;
}

var g = getGlobal();

//Add-In Commands
g.Do_OpenURLInTaskPane = Do_OpenURLInTaskPane;
```

My second attempt was to utilize 2x different HTML URLs in the `manifest.xml`

What I did was leave the original `taskpane.html` defined under the follow:

```
<FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
```

and

```
<SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
```

and

```
<Runtimes>
  <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
</Runtimes>
```

I then deleted the button that called this and defined two new buttons to open the URLs desired like so:

```
             <Control xsi:type="Button" id="FirstTPBT">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                      <SourceLocation resid="FirstTP.Url"/>
                  </Action>
              </Control>
              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="SecondTPBY">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                      <SourceLocation resid="SecondTP.Url"/>
                  </Action>
              </Control>
```

Basically, I'd prefer NOT to use `dialog` when gathering user input is required and use an individually tailored `taskpane` and then use `commands` when no input is required.

Looking for feedback on these options and/or reasons why to choose one method over the other or another approach all together.

Answer (score 1):

I have the your same issue, now i'm coding an Office Add-in for Excel (local and non shared runtime) and also i'm using React framework.
I tried two different way to perform this:

1. Using React-Router-Dom, i try to install this package to do a react routing but the Office Add-in block some features in browser and this type of solution not working;
2. Using Window element of html, for first i create an html template (.hbs) and i called "taskpane.html" and i copied all thing from taskpane.html to taskpane.hbs. I use this template because in that case i can use some parameter inside the html file. The main part of html file is this:

> ```
>   window.SOME_PARAMS = {
>     ENTRYPOINT: "{{htmlWebpackPlugin.options.entryPoint}}",
>   };
> ```

After that i modified the webpack.config.js adding different entry_point for every taskpane

> ```
> taskpane1: [
>   "./path/of/specific/entrypointJS/entrypoint.js"
> ]
> ```

At the end i use the params defined in html to navigate between different taskpane

> ```
> switch(window.SOME_PARAMS.ENTRYPOINT) {
>   case 'Taskpane1':
>     return (
>       ...
>     );
>       break;
>   case 'Taskpane2':
>     return(
>       ...
>     );
>   break;
>   case 'TaskPane3':
>     return(
>      ...
>     );
>     break;
> }
> ```

Your manifest file is correct, but you have to differentiate the urls of taskpane button

```
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane_1.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane-1.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane_2.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane-2.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane_2.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane-3.html"/>
```

Comment: Have you done much testing w/ this, any issues? I know I can get the multiple task panes to load, but I didn't test much beyond that.

Comment: Do you use the same `TaskPaneID` in your `manifest`?

Comment: No i didn't test much because I am in a phase of "research and development", i have different 'TaskPaneID", i created a custom ribbon with 3 taskpane. In practice I have 3 Control component all control components are equal to each other only all the ids of the children change and therefore all the taskpaneId also change

Comment: Personally I used the same TaskpaneID but so far it's work for me! Im also sorta in RnD phase, I've got the code mostly working just working on user input

Comment: Okok nice, I hope I was useful to you, let's say that I too am just learning the plug-in and its possible uses